# Java Swing - JFrame, change and show different content

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I'm trying to do a GUI Menu with three buttons. When I click on one button I want it to take me to another part of the menu. This means writing new content to my existing JFrame Content Pane. How do I do this properly?

Every time I try this the button gets stuck and it does not take me anywhere.
Instead It should take me to the next menu I have created.

I have tried removing all content in the Pane and then adding new.

I have put the JFrames content pane in a separate class that handles writing content to it.
Could this be a problem?

Solved:

All I had to do was to repaint and validate the content pane.
Thanks for all the help.

BR,
YAU

Comment: what do you have so far? You're going to have to add an `ActionListener` to the button, update the `JFrame` and call the `repaint()` method.

Comment: How should I update the JFrames content? Should I remove all the content from the content pane or create a new contentpane?

Comment: Depends on your requirements. I don't think building one from scratch is the best idea. You can loop through all the `Components` in the `JFrame` removing the ones you need to and then add all the new ones you need.

Comment: I have added a ActionListeners. In actionPerformed I set the frames content pane to a new pane containing my new menu.

Comment: ok did you call the `repaint()` method? You have to do `frame.repaint()` so the GUI knows to update.

Comment: Sorry for my short reply, I missed your previous reply.

When I call repaint I get a nullpointer: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at view.Display.repaint(Display.java:67)... 
 
The class Display handles the frame with it's content pane.
Hmm, why does it state that the frame, I'm trying to repaint, is null?